# How to make conditional arguments using argparse?

Tags: python, arguments, argparse

I have a file named `test.py`. There are 3 ways to use it:

1. You can load the contents of a json file, and it will generate graphs using that data (eg: `python test.py -l './data.json'`)
2. You can give it a YAML file, and it will use some information in it to generate a json file and then generate graphs (eg: `python test.py -y './user_input.yaml'`)
3. You can give it the information mentioned in point 2 through command line arguments (eg: `python test.py -s 50 -ftr '.pkl'`)

If `-l` is used, it won't need any of the arguments used in 2 or 3. If `-y` is used, it won't need any of the arguments from 1 and 2, and if the command-line arguments are given, it won't need any of the other arguments (but it *will* need the s and ftr arguments)

How would I set that up with argparse? One way would be to make if statements, and `if args.yaml is not None: <load from the yaml file>`, but the problem with that is I would prefer an argument required error to pop up if option 3 is chosen but not all the arguments are given. Is there a way to use argparse that would satisfy my need?

Comment: `mutually_exclusive_group` should handle the '-l' vs '-y' case.  '-s' could be part of the group if it didn't also expect '-ftr'.  For more complicated things, I'm recommending testing after parsing.  The key purpose of `argparse` is understand what your user wants; don't design a parser that's hard to explain.